# Why is my Node.js function not changing the admin field to true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I am making a simple message board app and some logic that changes certain users admin field to true based on their email address. Everything else is working as expected except this functionality.

My approach to this problem was adding an optional admin field to my User model that has a default boolean value of false. On registration my app will look for a predetermined email and if it finds a match, it will then update the admin value to true. It seems pretty simple but it is not working. Here is a sample of the code so you can see my thought process (I took out the stuff that is relevant to this question):

```
//This is my user registration logic
exports.register_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const admin = await User.findOne({email: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL}).exec(); //find user based on the email they register will


        if (admin) {
            try {
                const result = await admin.updateOne({ email: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL }, { admin: true }).exec(); //update the 
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error updating admin status:', err);
                return res.status(500).send('Error updating admin status');
            }
        }
        // Create new user
        const user = new User({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword, // Use the hashed password
        });

        await user.save();

        // Redirect after successful registration
        res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    posts: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post"},
    admin: {type: Boolean, default: false},
})
```

The thing that is confusing me the most is that my error handling code is not being triggered either. It just creates the user like it would before I added this function. The only thing that I can think of as a solution would to be to move the logic to change the admin field AFTER the new user is created. However, that did not work for me either.

Comment: Do you mean to set the new user's `admin` to `true`? This code reads as though you are constantly setting the same email to `{admin:true}`. I suspect that `process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL` doesn't have the value you expect it to have and so `User.findOne` resolves to `null`. hence why that if block is being skipped all together. Try printing the contents of `process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any admin logic being handled concerning the new user who is being registered.

When the function starts, compare the `req.body.email` to the `process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL`. If true then add an `admin: true` value to your user initializer and save the user.

I am sorry if I misunderstood your question but this seems about it.